# How can I reference back to objects/components of a parent object after destroyed it and re instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have in the Hierarchy one scene and 3 parent objects. The 3 parent objects are :

Game Data (Where all the gameplay objects are childs of it)

Main Menu

Game Manager (That control on pausing/unpausing the game in some cases)

The idea the main goal is when the game start it's starting with the main menu then when clicking the start new game button it will start the game when hit the escape key it will be back to the main menu and again I can start a new game or resuming the game. I also did that while the game is running if you hit the P button it will pause/unpause the game.

First the script that is attached to the Game Manager :

Here I'm doing a reference for the Dialogue System, Depth Of Field, Main Menu And in the bottom I'm using find to find back the Depth Of Field and the Dialogue System since I'm destroying the Game Data object when starting a new game :

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject dialogueSystem;
     public DepthOfField depthOfField;
     public static bool gamepaused = false;

     public GameObject mainMenu;

     private void Start()
     {
         Time.timeScale = 0f;
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
         {
             gamepaused = !gamepaused;

             if (gamepaused)
             {
                 Time.timeScale = 0f;
             }
             else
             {
                 Time.timeScale = 1f;
             }
         }

         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
         {
             if(depthOfField == null || dialogueSystem == null)
             {
                 depthOfField = GameObject.Find("Player Camera").GetComponent<DepthOfField>();
                 dialogueSystem = GameObject.Find("Dialogue System");
             }
             depthOfField.DepthOfFieldInit(3f);
             Time.timeScale = 0f;
             dialogueSystem.SetActive(false);
             mainMenu.SetActive(true);

             Cursor.visible = true;
             Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
         }
     }
 }
```

The problem is that the Dialogue System and Depth Of Field are in the Game Data and when I destroy the Game Data and instantiate the Game Data using a prefab over again to make a new game to start the variables in the GameController script lost reference and I need to use find. But using find so many times is a good idea ?

This script the next one is attached to the Main Menu :

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject gameDataPrefab;
     public GameObject gameData;
     public GameObject mainMenu;

     public void StartNewGame()
     {
         var gdata = GameObject.Find("Game Data");
         if (gdata != null)
         {
             Destroy(gdata);
         }

         GameObject go = Instantiate(gameDataPrefab);
         go.name = "Game Data";

         mainMenu.SetActive(false);
         GameController.gamepaused = false;
         Time.timeScale = 1f;
     }

     public void ResumeGame()
     {

     }

     public void QuitGame()
     {
         Application.Quit();
     }
 }
```

Here when I click the UI button to start a new game in the function StartNewGame I destroy the Game Data and create a new one. This make the variables in the GameController script to lost references.

The last script is attached to the Game Data this script I'm calling the method DepthOfFieldInit to make effect when I hit the escape key back to the Main Menu.

The problem is that some variables are lost references since the Game Data is destroyed. For example I'm getting null on :

```
playerLockMode.PlayerLockState(true, true);
```

Since playerLockMode is also on the Game Data that have been destroyed.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.PostProcessing;

 public class DepthOfField : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public UnityEngine.GameObject player;
     public PostProcessingProfile postProcessingProfile;
     public bool dephOfFieldFinished = false;
     public LockSystem playerLockMode;

     private Animator playerAnimator;
     private float clipLength;
     private Coroutine depthOfFieldRoutineRef;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         if (depthOfFieldRoutineRef != null)
         {
             StopCoroutine(depthOfFieldRoutineRef);
         }

         playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

         AnimationClip[] clips = playerAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
         foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
         {
             clipLength = clip.length;
         }

         DepthOfFieldInit(clipLength);

         // Don't forget to set depthOfFieldRoutineRef to null again at the end of routine!
     }

     public void DepthOfFieldInit(float duration)
     {
         var depthOfField = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;
         depthOfField.focalLength = 300;
         StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(depthOfField.focalLength, 1, duration));
         postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
     }

     public IEnumerator changeValueOverTime(float fromVal, float toVal, float duration)
     {
         playerLockMode.PlayerLockState(true, true);

         float counter = 0f;

         while (counter < duration)
         {
             var dof = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;

             counter += Time.deltaTime;

             float val = Mathf.Lerp(fromVal, toVal, counter / duration);

             dof.focalLength = val;
             postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = dof;

             yield return null;
         }

         playerAnimator.enabled = false;
         dephOfFieldFinished = true;
         depthOfFieldRoutineRef = null;
     }
 }
```

But I don't understand if I instantiate right away back the Game Data when starting a new game why the variables lost references ? And is there a better way to use Find at any place many times after the Game Data have been destroyed ? And maybe the whole code in the StartNewGame is wrong ?

My main goal is when clicking the StartNewGame start over a new game. When hit the escape key pause the game and go back to the main menu.

Here is a screenshot of my Hierarchy :

[image: Hierarchy]

Comment: When you destroy an object and instantiate a new object, all your references are lost because *they're different objects.* C# isn't magic.

Comment: @Draco18s I know that I wonder how in games they make a start new game ? If not using scenes loading.  The destroy and creating the objects or using game state ? What is the proper way to start a new game ?

Comment: Depends on the game. In all cases, the player object doesn't actually get referenced directly. Instead either a `Game.GetPlayer()` method exists or the player data is stored separately from the object-in-the-world representation.